# How do two of my Wilcoxon signed rank tests have the same p-values?

Tags: p-value, nonparametric, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I'm running a statistical analysis where I'm comparing land surface temperature in matched equal sized areas (project areas and control areas) of different cities. In each city, I do it for two different years (2009 and 2019). I extracted values in ArcGIS from Landsat land surface temperature rasters. In most cities so far, this has worked out as expected. For the last two cities that I did, the 2009 projects vs controls Wilcoxon signed rank had the same p-value as the 2019 projects vs controls Wilcoxon signed rank. I can't for the life of my figure out why this is happening. It seems very unlikely.

Here's the data first. Clearly the 2009 data is different from the 2019 data.

```
> atlanta_temps_2009 <- read.csv(file="C:/Users/melis/Documents/UrbanRenewal/Output/Spreadsheets/atlanta_TempStats_2009.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
> atlanta_temps_2019 <- read.csv(file="C:/Users/melis/Documents/UrbanRenewal/Output/Spreadsheets/atlanta_TempStats_2019.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

> atlanta_temps_2009
                     project MIN_p MAX_p RANGE_p   MEAN_p    STD_p MEDIAN_p MIN_c MAX_c RANGE_c   MEAN_c    STD_c MEDIAN_c
1                  Butler St  3151  3260     109 3202.068 22.61865     3204  3109  3304     195 3191.912 31.88033     3195
2       Buttermilk Bts-N Ave  3124  3272     148 3206.892 31.57063     3210  3158  3239      81 3202.340 21.63346     3202
3               Bedford-Pine  3146  3230      84 3185.864 14.99432     3187  3116  3328     212 3197.184 34.77846     3195
4                   West End  3093  3289     196 3170.204 39.96014     3162  3052  3332     280 3127.463 52.47293     3106
5  Transportation Plaza (Fs)  3141  3327     186 3220.775 28.48240     3217  3052  3309     257 3171.043 49.70042     3176
6                   Rockdale  3043  3232     189 3101.295 41.52683     3093  3034  3227     193 3097.820 33.10996     3094
7                Thomasville  3045  3203     158 3112.903 35.26001     3110  3037  3169     132 3072.637 22.35470     3070
8               Georgia Tech  3153  3229      76 3178.663 15.25831     3177  3161  3243      82 3209.412 16.11734     3213
9          University Center  3119  3253     134 3190.463 24.29390     3191  3060  3231     171 3145.687 28.31763     3145
10         Rawson-Washington  3136  3275     139 3200.240 29.16273     3201  3060  3241     181 3164.900 37.14228     3164
11             West End (Gn)  3093  3289     196 3170.200 39.98566     3162  3052  3332     280 3127.452 52.48603     3106

> atlanta_temps_2019
                 project MIN_p MAX_p RANGE_p   MEAN_p    STD_p MEDIAN_p MIN_c MAX_c RANGE_c   MEAN_c    STD_c MEDIAN_c
1                  Butler St  3139  3220      81 3175.855 15.92880     3176  3097  3266     169 3165.147 33.24803     3161
2       Buttermilk Bts-N Ave  3122  3241     119 3173.626 26.50905     3170  3131  3222      91 3175.215 23.30458     3177
3               Bedford-Pine  3105  3196      91 3156.944 16.23514     3160  3119  3217      98 3164.361 18.24806     3162
4                   West End  3088  3230     142 3147.344 30.47870     3140  3039  3301     262 3112.059 44.39971     3097
5  Transportation Plaza (Fs)  3099  3294     195 3191.578 29.72980     3189  3042  3287     245 3153.352 43.75560     3154
6                   Rockdale  3044  3193     149 3094.167 35.00997     3086  3041  3186     145 3088.398 26.46826     3085
7                Thomasville  3040  3149     109 3096.100 19.58116     3095  3033  3116      83 3057.488 17.42419     3055
8               Georgia Tech  3125  3196      71 3153.067 12.99396     3151  3144  3202      58 3175.889 11.41275     3175
9          University Center  3093  3223     130 3155.862 23.35986     3156  3058  3189     131 3123.079 24.80023     3121
10         Rawson-Washington  3127  3243     116 3176.015 24.56366     3173  3068  3217     149 3151.890 28.17006     3155
11             West End (Gn)  3088  3230     142 3147.364 30.49558     3140  3039  3301     262 3112.039 44.40146     3097
```

And here's the Wilcoxon signed rank test. I thought at first it may be due to a relatively low n (11) because both cities where this is happening have n=11, but I did the same analysis with cities with n=7 or 8, and it worked fine.

```
> wilcoxsign_test(atlanta_temps_2009$MEAN_p ~ atlanta_temps_2009$MEAN_c)

    Asymptotic Wilcoxon-Pratt Signed-Rank Test

data:  y by x (pos, neg) 
     stratified by block
Z = 2.1339, p-value = 0.03285
alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0

> wilcoxsign_test(atlanta_temps_2019$MEAN_p ~ atlanta_temps_2019$MEAN_c)

    Asymptotic Wilcoxon-Pratt Signed-Rank Test

data:  y by x (pos, neg) 
     stratified by block
Z = 2.1339, p-value = 0.03285
alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
```

I would very much appreciate any insight into what I've done wrong. Thanks!

Comment: The datasets are small enough to conduct the test by hand, which is instructive.  You only need to compute the test statistics, since both datasets are the same size and there are no ties.  Is there a reason why you are not using the built-in `wilcox.test`?  What exactly does your `wilcoxsign_test` do?

Comment: @whuber I used wilcoxsign_test instead of wilcox.test to use the Pratt zero handling method. Thanks. I'll try it by hand and see.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Melissa.  Since you have no tied values, that should not matter.

Comment: As whuber suggested, manually compute the sum R value, you can do this in Excel in about 15 minutes. What you will find is W=48 both datasets.  Thus the test statistic is z=48/sqrt(506) for both sets.  Yes, unlikely but possible!